# Как рисовать элементы игрового интерфейса в окне GLFW?

Tags: opengl, glfw

Мне нужно отрисовать интерфейс для игры на opengl, но проблема в том, что он позволяет рисовать только полигоны. Ведь не рисовать же каждую кнопку посредством полигонов? Есть ли какие-нибудь библиотеки позволяющие рисовать 2д спрайты в окне glfw? Или это нормальная практика рисовать каждый символ, каждую кнопку посредством полигонов?

Comment: Вы удивитесь, но спрайт тоже рисуется на полигоне. А кнопка, это просто текстура кнопки (или несколько, если у нее есть состояния и/или анимация, и иногда свой шейдер, если там какая-то хитрая анимация). Причем кнопки обычно рисуются 9-patch. Но это уже специфика.